# Most efficient way to get booking data for time period?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a booking system that allows a user to book places for 30 min timeslots (e.g. 1pm, 1:30pm, 2pm etc...)

In the sql database I may have one booking for 10am, a booking for 1pm and two for 2pm. I am trying to display a view of all 30 min booking slots in between a date time range displaying number of current bookings for each slot.

I am not storing each slot explicitly as it's not very efficient. Is there a way to make sql return 'empty' timeslots in a single query?  I don't want to create a timeslot array then query each timeslot individually for the total count of bookings.

I am using sql server and asp.net mvc6 as my technology base. Some suggestions on technique would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you need to build a 30 minute interval time range table and do `left join` with your table to get all time slots

This query generates 30 minute interval times starting from startDate , total 12 time slots are generated, you can modify it accordingly.

```
declare @startDate datetime ='2014-01-12 12:00:00'

;with cte(value,nextval,n)
as
(
   select CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@startDate,108) as value,  
       dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, @startDate)+30, 0) as nextval, 1 as n
   union all
   select  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),cte.nextval,108) as value, 
       dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, cte.nextval)+30, 0) as nextval, n+1
   from cte
   where n <=12
)
select * from cte
left join Table1
on cte.nextval = Table1.timeslotvalue
```

Comment: Thank you for this..i "think" i understand it.  The 30 min interval time range would need to have a "slot" for every item in a 24 hour period?